# How can I disable Visual Studio's default build and replace it with a custom build tool?

Tags: build, visual-studio-2017, ninja

I'm trying to use [Ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) to build my C++ projects in Visual Studio and I have a basic setup to compile and link through the command line which I've tested successfully.

I'm now trying to integrate this into Visual Studio and I want to completely replace the default build with this custom build tool, while still taking my project settings into account. When I right click my project and click build, I want it to run this custom build tool that I have set up in the project properties. At the moment it seems to do a regular build and completely ignores the custom build step. If I right click on my custom build file and click compile, then it will perform the custom build step.

Custom build output - when I right click and compile the custom build tool file

```
1>------ Build started: Project: test, Configuration: TEST x64 ------
1>Performing Custom Build Tools
1>[1/1] cl /Fo:build\obj\ /EHsc test.cpp test2.cpp
1>Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.16.27024.1 for x64
1>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
1>
1>test.cpp
1>test2.cpp
1>Generating Code...
1>Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.16.27024.1
1>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
1>
1>/out:test.exe
1>build\obj\test.obj
1>build\obj\test2.obj
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Rebuild all on the project

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: test, Configuration: TEST x64 ------
1>Performing Custom Build Tools
1>[1/1] cl /Fo:build\obj\ /EHsc test.cpp test2.cpp
1>Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.16.27024.1 for x64
1>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
1>
1>test.cpp
1>test2.cpp
1>Generating Code...
1>Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.16.27024.1
1>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
1>
1>/out:test.exe
1>build\obj\test.obj
1>build\obj\test2.obj
1>pch.cpp
1>test.cpp
1>test2.cpp
1>Generating Code...
1>test.vcxproj -> C:\Users\user\source\repos\test\x64\TEST\test.exe
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

With the latter output, it looks like it's performing the builds twice. Once with visual studio (which I don't want) and once with the custom build tool.

Is there a way that I can click build on my project, and it will *only* perform my custom build?

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't think this is the correct solution, I have found something that works.

You can edit the `.vcxproj` file to remove all of the `ClCompile` commands.

Before

```
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='TEST|x64'">
     <ClCompile>
      <AdditionalOptions />
    </ClCompile>
    <CustomBuild>
      <Command>"C:\Users\user\Desktop\ninja.exe" -f build.ninja</Command>
      <Outputs>build/obj</Outputs>
    </CustomBuild>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="pch.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="test-private-pch.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="test-public-pch.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="test2.h" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompileInclude="pch.cpp">
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">Create</PrecompiledHeader>
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">Create</PrecompiledHeader>
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">Create</PrecompiledHeader>
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">Create</PrecompiledHeader>
    </ClInclude>
    <ClCompileInclude Include="test.cpp" />
    <ClCompileInclude Include="test2.cpp" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

After

```
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='TEST|x64'">
<!--     <ClCompile>
      <AdditionalOptions />
    </ClCompile> -->
    <CustomBuild>
      <Command>"C:\Users\user\Desktop\ninja.exe" -f build.ninja</Command>
      <Outputs>build/obj</Outputs>
    </CustomBuild>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="pch.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="test-private-pch.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="test-public-pch.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="test2.h" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="pch.cpp">
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">Create</PrecompiledHeader>
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">Create</PrecompiledHeader>
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">Create</PrecompiledHeader>
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">Create</PrecompiledHeader>
    </ClInclude>
    <ClInclude Include="test.cpp" />
    <ClInclude Include="test2.cpp" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Changing the `ClCompile` on the .cpp files to `ClInclude` means that they are still visible in the project and can be changed.

Rebuild all output after the change

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: test, Configuration: TEST x64 ------
1>Performing Custom Build Tools
1>[1/1] cl /Fo:build\obj\ /EHsc test.cpp test2.cpp
1>Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.16.27024.1 for x64
1>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
1>
1>test.cpp
1>test2.cpp
1>Generating Code...
1>Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.16.27024.1
1>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
1>
1>/out:test.exe
1>build\obj\test.obj
1>build\obj\test2.obj
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Now when I rebuild this single project, only my custom build will run. If anyone has a better solution to this feel free to post an answer.